# jnetpcap for android development on linux

Tags: android, java-native-interface, jnetpcap

If have downloaded the latest jnetpcap version and installed it on my linux machine (copied the libjnetpcap.so to /usr/lib and set the PATH). I used eclipse to test the library in a simple JAVA PROJECT which worked fine. But in my ANDROID PROJECT in eclipse I receive the error

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.jnetpcap.Pcap
```

Is it even possible to use this library in an ANDROID PROJECT because everything worked for my JAVA PROJECT?

Is there another possibility to use Pcap functions maybe with JNI and implement the relevant functions in C?

Answer (score 0):

You have to install Jnetpcap on the target host as well as your development host. Whether that's even possible in Android is another question, but there's no indication here that you have even tried it.